# Lakehouse Federation in Unity Catalog integration with Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks-unity-catalog

Our use case is to make our data which lives in Snowflake available in Databricks (along with use cases in Snowflake itself). Data in Snowflake could reach terabytes in size,

For this purpose, I was looking at Lakehouse Federation in Unity Catalog and exploring that path.

But wanted to see if this is a good idea because won't this approach require doubling the compute to query a large amount of data: one compute from the Snowflake side to fetch the original data from its origin, and the second from Databricks to submit a query and handle results.

Wanted to check with experts, what are their thoughts on this? Also if not this path, what other way would you choose to solve for this use case?

Comment: We are using Lakehouse Federation.  I am also concerned about speed and cost.  We are going to test having DLT replicate Snowflake tables into Delta with a Unity Catalog governance layer.  How can we create and update Unity permission to = Snowflake?